# C++ Allegro5 CodeBlocks Linker

Tags: c++, codeblocks, allegro

I'm running Ubuntu.  I followed each and every step in the http://wiki.allegro.cc for installation and set up of Allegro5.  If I run my program from the command line, I know I need to use

```
 gcc -Wall main.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs allegro-5.0
```

plus any other packges I use. (I don't know what all of it means, but I know I need it)

What I need help with if figuring out what I need to do in Codeblocks > Settings > Compiler so that it will link to the allegro library so that I don't get a hundred and one undefined reference errors.  I don't know what I'm looking for, and I don't know where to look. Help a new guy out.
Thanks.

*edit:* I know I'd need 
    `allegro-config --libs --static`
in the Linker for Allegro 4.2

Where can I look and what do I need for Allegro5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Codeblocks doesn't support entering `` `pkg-config --cflags --libs allegro-5.0` `` directly, then just open up a terminal and type in (no backticks):

`pkg-config --cflags --libs allegro-5.0`

Then copy/paste the result of that into the compiler settings inside Codeblocks.